# Specific Rsync script not running with cron

Tags: backup, cron, rsync

I've tried other rsync scripts with these machines and they work fine. However, this one doesn't. I suspect it has to do with the fact that it's broken up in 2 parts. I've tried to put it in crontab -e, cron.d and cron.daily. Still doesn't work. This is the script that's causing problems (I want it to run daily):

```
find /path/backups/ -type f -mtime -2 -printf '%P\n' | rsync -avz --progress --delete --exclude-from=- -e "ssh -p 512" /path/backups/ me@host:/remote/path/server-backups/
```

Comment: what errors you get?

Comment: Oh, I should've probably mention that I get no errors. Here are the logs: Jan 21 15:32:01 servername CRON[14654]: (serveruser) CMD (find /path/backups/
 -type f -mtime -2 -printf ')
It only runs the first part of the script